# Slack notification via AlertManager - some buttons missing in Slack Desktop App

Tags: slack, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a Slack notification configured for AlertManager:

```
receivers:
  - name: "team:slack"
    slack_configs:
      - channel: "alerts" 
        icon_emoji: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.icon" . }}'
        color: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.color" . }}'
        title: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.title" . }}'
        title_link: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.link" . }}'
        text: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.text" . }} (notify <!subteam^S04*****>)'
        send_resolved: true
        api_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/***/***/*****"
        actions:
          - type: button
            text: "Runbook :green_book:"
            url: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.runbook_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "View :mag:"
            url: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.alert_source_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Dashboard :chart_with_upwards_trend:"
            url: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.dashboard_url" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Mute :no_bell:"
            url: !unsafe '{{ template "__alert_silence_link" . }}'
          - type: button
            text: "Docs :books:"
            url: !unsafe '{{ template "slack.my.doc_url" . }}'
```

The strange thing is that when a notification received in Slack Mobile App - I see all 5 buttons, but when in Slack Desktop APP - I see only first 3 buttons, and no Mute and Docs buttons.

Here is a part of my custom template for buggy buttons:

```
{{ define "__alert_silence_link" -}}
    {{ .ExternalURL }}/#/silences/new?filter=%7B
    {{- range .CommonLabels.SortedPairs -}}
        {{- if ne .Name "alertname" -}}
            {{- .Name }}%3D%22{{- .Value | urlquery -}}%22%2C%20
        {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
    alertname%3D%22{{- .CommonLabels.alertname -}}%22%7D
{{- end }}

{{ define "slack.my.doc_url" }}
    {{- if ne (index .Alerts 0).Annotations.doc_url "" -}}
        {{- (index .Alerts 0).Annotations.doc_url -}}
    {{- end -}}
{{- end }}
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding a name property for each button

Comment: it's good if you add some sample code to make your point better